# How to correctly use WHERE with JOIN in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to implement a JOIN in my PHP but I don't know how to include the WHERE clause with JOIN in my query.

I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT SpecialFacts.ConservationStatus, SpecialFacts.Reproduction, SpecialFacts.Length, Habitat.Type, Habitat.located

FROM SpecialFacts

INNER JOIN Habitat ON SpecialFacts.SpeciesID=Habitat.SpeciesID

WHERE SpeciesID="G. cuvier"
```

Basically I'm trying to make sure the join happens on the tables where the SpeciesID is G. cuvier but everything I have tried so far doesn't work and the error it is giving me now is "Column SpeciesID in where clause is ambiguous".

Here is my relevant PHP code:

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT SpecialFacts.ConservationStatus, SpecialFacts.Reproduction, SpecialFacts.Length, Habitat.Type, Habitat.located FROM SpecialFacts INNER JOIN Habitat ON SpecialFacts.SpeciesID=Habitat.SpeciesID WHERE SpeciesID='G. cuvier'") or die("fail" . mysqli_error($connect));


$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[$i];
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `SpeciesID` exists in both tables, so it doesn't know which need to be compared to value given as `G. cuvier`.  As you are writing every column name as table name with dot(.), the same should be in where condition column `SpecialFacts.SpeciesID = "G. cuvier"`.

So query should be like:

```
SELECT SpecialFacts.ConservationStatus, SpecialFacts.Reproduction, SpecialFacts.Length, Habitat.Type, Habitat.located

FROM SpecialFacts

INNER JOIN Habitat ON SpecialFacts.SpeciesID=Habitat.SpeciesID

WHERE SpecialFacts.SpeciesID="G. cuvier"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not giving you that error because you're using `WHERE` incorrectly. It's giving you that error because there are multiple tables in your query that have a column with that name, hence the "ambiguous". You just need to disambiguate it by adding the table name to the identifier.

```
WHERE SpecialFacts.SpeciesID="G. cuvier"
```

or

```
WHERE Habitat.SpeciesID="G. cuvier"
```

Since you're inner joining the tables on that column, either table should work for the WHERE clause. I would suggest using the smaller table for performance reasons, but honestly I'm not 100% certain if it will matter or not. You can do `EXPLAIN` on each one to see how they compare.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query instead

```
SELECT SpecialFacts.ConservationStatus, SpecialFacts.Reproduction, SpecialFacts.Length, Habitat.Type, Habitat.located
FROM SpecialFacts INNER JOIN Habitat 
ON SpecialFacts.SpeciesID=Habitat.SpeciesID
WHERE SpecialFacts.SpeciesID='G. cuvier'
```

I have used single quote and used column name with table name.